# Custom resolver or Type converter for AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a situation like -

```
internal class A
{
   public List<T> li{ get; set; }

}

internal class B
{
   public List<T> li2 { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<A,B>();
```

Now I have -

```
internal class C
{
   public string S1{ get; set; }
   public string S2{ get; set; }
}
```

And the condtion is if `C.S1 == "X"`, populate a new `T` and add to the `List<T>` of `B`.

Is it possible using custom `ValueResolver` or `TypeConverter`?
As of Now, if I use`CreateMap<..>.ResolveUsing<CustomResolverThatIWrote>()` the previous value mapped from `A.li` is overwritten.

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question how classes A, B and C are related. Your condition involves both B and C but how does that work, does C have a B property - or the other way round?

Comment: No, but I'll create a new instance of `T` depending on the value of `C.S1`. the value of `C.S2` will be assigned to on of the property of the new instance .And that instance need to be added to the `B.li2`.

Comment: Basically what I want to achieve is to have the `B.li2.Count == A.li.Count + 1` if `C.S1 == "X"`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You're mapping A to B but you want to have a condition based on C? Where does the instance of C come from?

Comment: I consume two wcf operations, and I need to populate my response using them both.